# "Negative definite" in the definition of Morse index

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, hessian-matrix, morse-theory

Wikipedia and other sources say that the index of a non-degenerate critical point $p$ of a manifold $M$ is "the dimension of the largest subspace of $T_p\left(M\right)$ on which the Hessian is negative definite."

I know what it means for a matrix to be negative definite, but am not sure how this is relevant.  Certainly, the Hessian of $f$ at the point $p$ is either negative definite or it isn't.  Does Hessian here mean, e.g., for $f(x, y) = x^3 - y^3$,

$$\begin{pmatrix}6x & 0 \\ 0 & -6y\end{pmatrix}$$
as a function of $x$ and $y$?  If so, it's not clear why this matrix why the set of $\left(x, y\right)$ for which this matrix is negative definite should form a subspace.  To find the eigenvalues of this matrix (call it $H$), I must find the roots of $\det\left(H - \lambda\cdot I\right) = 0$.  But $\det\left(A + B\right)\neq \det A\:+\:\det B$ in general, so that it's not clear why the matrix is negative definite for $\left(x_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2\right)$ just because it's so for $\left(x_1, y_1\right) + \left(x_2, y_2\right)$.

Comment: Partial insight: $A + B$ is negative definite if $A$ and $B$ are, and $r\cdot A$ is negative definite if $r > 0$ and $A$ is.  But a subspace must be closed under scalar multiplication generally and not just by multiplication by a positive ... in fact, if $r < 0$ and $A$ is negative definite then $r\cdot A$ is *positive* definite.

Comment: [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Definitions_and_properties) here is not taken as a function of $x$ and $y$, it is computed at a fixed point, the critical point. It defines a symmetric bilinear form on the tangent space, and it makes sense to talk about its subspaces where this form is negative definite.

Comment: @Conifold Would you mind elaborating for someone not too familiar with bilinear forms?  For example, by "its" subspaces, you mean subspaces of the tangent space?  And why does it make sense to talk about these subspaces?

Comment: Yes, subspaces of the tangent space, and the largest subspace where the form is negative definite is the sum of eigenspaces of $H$ with negative eigenvalues (more or less obviously).

Comment: @Conifold I'm afraid I still don't understand.  If definiteness is a property of the form itself (equivalent to its underlying matrix being definite), then how can it be definite "on a subspace"?  Since the form is defined at a point, wouldn't it either be definite or not definite?  I looked at [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_quadratic_form) and gained no new insights.

Comment: Any form can be restricted to a subspace by taking vectors in $(Hu,u)$ from it. It may be indefinite on the whole space but definite when so restricted.